# Best way to compare multiples vars shell linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have an Ansible playbook which collects some informations and finally write into a file something like this :

```
VAR_A=14.12.103
VAR_B=14.12.103
VAR_C=14.12.103
VAR_D=14.12.103
VAR_E=14.12.103
VAR_F=14.12.103
VAR_G=14.12.103
VAR_H=14.12.103
```

Then, I use a shell script to compare theses values to be sure that every vars are each identical to the other.

What is the best way to compare theses vars ? Actually I do :

```
if [ "$VAR_A" = "$VAR_B" ] && [ "$VAR_B" = "$VAR_C" ] && [ "$VAR_C" = "$VAR_D" ] && [ "$VAR_D" = "$VAR_E" ] && [ "$VAR_E" = "$VAR_F" ] && [ "$VAR_F" = "$VAR_G" ] && [ "$VAR_G" = "$VAR_H" ]; then
  echo "OK"
  exit 0
else
  echo "KO"
  exit 2
fi
```

but i think that's not the best way..

Does somebody gots another solution ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> finally write into a file something like this :

I would:

```
[[ "$(sed 's/^VAR_[A-H]=//' file | uniq | wc -l)" -eq 1 ]]
```

That could be significantly slower, but more readable. An `awk` solution could be significantly faster.

I think in awk, you could, untested:

```
if awk -F'=' 'NR==1{l=$2} NR!=1{if ($2 != l) exit 1}' file; then
```

Comment: Insipred to your answer, I do it : 
if [ $(awk -F "=" '{print $2 }' file | sort | uniq | wc -l) -gt 1 ]; then
  echo KO
else
  echo OK
fi

It works pretty good

Comment: If you are using awk, that's little sense for the whole line and to run 3 processes to do it. Do all the operations, ie. all the `| sort | uniq | wc -l) -gt 1` inside `awk`... I think along `awk -F'=' 'NR==1{l=$2} NR!=1{if ($2 != l) exit 1}`. Still that will break if variable value contains `=`

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you define "best"?
Are you looking for runtime?
or clarity?

because you can use a loop to compare `VAR_A` to all others, and if any comparison is false return `KO` else `OK`.

I can't think of a way to make it faster in bash but will edit if anything comes to mind.

Comment: I prefer clarity

Answer (score 1):

Using awk you may use:

```
if awk -F= 'NR == 1 {v = $2} $2 != v {exit 1}' file; then
   echo "OK"
   exit 0
else
   echo "KO"
   exit 2
fi
```